# Gradual migration of a .Net Framework (4.6) solution to .Net 5?

Tags: .net, wpf, .net-core, .net-standard

Our company's main software product is a WPF application consisting of around 40 projects, and I'd like to start porting it to .Net 5. The solution is still under constant, active development, which I presume would make it impractical to do a big-bang migration. Instead, is it possible to migrate the projects one at a time (during lulls in our regular dev work), and if so what would be the recommended approach? I'm vaguely aware of concepts like multi-targeting and a compatibility shim but don't really understand them, and the whole .Net Standard thing passed me by too, so I never really got my head around that one either!

The UI projects reference an 8 year old charting library, and upgrading this isn't practical at the moment due to the number of breaking changes that this would bring, so I guess this rules out being able to migrate the UI projects? Therefore I'd like to start migrating the business logic projects to .Net 5, assuming this is even possible - i.e. can a solution contain a mix of Framework and Core projects, referencing one another?

What about the myriad of referenced NuGet packages? What is the implication of migrating a Framework project to .Net 5? Does NuGet take care of updating the package or is this a manual step? What happens if a package doesn't support .Net 5?

Comment: My comment would be to justify the rationale to migrate to .NET 5 first. While full .NET Framework stopped at 4.8, if there is no significant benefit to migrate this WPF application to .NET 5 but just for catching up new stuff, then maybe you want to wait for .NET 6 which is a LTS (.NET 5 EOL around May 2022).

Answer (score 1):

Migration from and old .NET Framework from latest is always a headache , But you are moving from .NET Framework to .NET 5 you must first move your whole Application to .NET Standard as this is the only medium common between all .NET Framework.

once you are migrated NuGet does not care upgrading the package it is a manual step , as Packages like Entity framework ,and entity framework core , signal r core and simple single R , The packages you have to reinstall the latest one then with few tweaks you can change you implemented functions from old to new by reading documentation of Microsoft provided for given packages

Kindly Read the following article
[enter link description here](https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/dotnet/desktop/wpf/migration/convert-project-from-net-framework?view=netdesktop-5.0&preserve-view=true)